# How to force owner permissions for a group or project?

Tags: gitlab

I have a self-hosted gitlab instance. The problem is a few projects/groups are owned by people who aren't around anymore, which leaves others unable to add people to these projects.

Given that I have SSH access to the gitlab server, is there any way to manually override who the owner of a particular group/project is?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Have to use a Gitlab admin account (wasn't aware there was such a thing since I didn't install Gitlab).

Can do this either with the default admin account (admin@local.host) or by elevating another user to admin. This can be done via SSH by opening a Rails console on Gitlab and setting `user.admin = true` then `user.save`.

See https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-reset-the-admin-password-via-the-rails-console/223

Personally (on Gitlab 6.3) I had issues resetting the original admin password because the query generated by the `save` method had a condition for `id != 1`, so it was easier to just make another admin account instead of trying to work around that.